# Problemas na JSP utiliando JSTL e JBOSS

Tags: jsp, maven, jboss

Fiz um Hello World para testar a aplicação mas a página JSP não está sendo renderizada.

Só aparece o código fonte da página.

Existe alguma configuração extra?

Inclusive coloquei todas as dependências no meu POM.xml.

Comment: [Esse](http://www.coderanch.com/t/90964/JBoss/deploy-servelts-jsp-JBoss) ou [esse](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.0.Final/en/GettingStartedGuide/html/jsp_application.html) *link* ajuda em algo?

Comment: Não ajudou muito não cara...

Comment: Se não tiver resolvido ainda, inclua na pergunta este `JSP` (e se ele tiver sendo retornado em um *servlet*, o *servlet* também), além do seu `pom.xml`, talvez consigamos ajudá-lo. Se tiver resolvido, considere incluir uma resposta à sua pergunta, pode ajudar outras pessoas =)